# Adding/appending objects to a newly created json array with same keys via jq in bash script

Tags: arrays, json, bash, append, jq

I am having a real hard time in attempting to iteratively append new values over a newly created JSON array/file from the same bash script.
Consider the following simple script snippet:

```
echo "Enter name: "
read name
echo "Enter Car Model: "
read car
echo "Enter Colour: "
read colour

echo
jq -n --arg name "$name" --arg car "$car" --arg colour "$colour" '{"profiles":[{"name": $name, "car": $car, "colour": $colour}]}' > model.json
echo
cat model.json | jq .
```

This outputs:

```
Enter name:
Joe
Enter Car Model:
BMW
Enter Colour:
Red

{
  "profiles": [
    {
      "name": "Joe",
      "car": "BMW",
      "colour": "Red"
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want it to eventually do is something like this, dynamically:

```
Enter name:
Joe
Enter Car Model:
BMW
Enter Colour:
Red

{
  "profiles": [
    {
      "name": "Joe",
      "car": "BMW",
      "colour": "Red"
    },
    {
      "name": "Peter",
      "car": "Nissan",
      "colour": "White"
    }
  ]
}
```

etc...

I understand I'll need to utilise a loop after the first set of key:value entries, but then how would I append to the newly created model.json file as opposed to overriding the initial values via jq in a bash script?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append the object, you can use the idiom:

```
.profiles += [...]
```

Because of the friendly way jq handles `null`, the above will also work initially.

Incidentally, you can abbreviate key-value pairs such as

```
"name": $name
```

to just the variable name:

```
$name
```

### Example

For the sake of uniformity, it might make sense to prepopulate model.json with `null`, e.g.

```
echo null > model.json
```

Then you can invoke jq uniformly (without the -n option), e.g.

```
jq --arg name "$name" --arg car "$car" --arg colour "$colour" '
  .profiles += [{ $name, $car, $colour}]
' model.json | sponge model.json
```

Caveat: overwriting the input file using `sponge` without taking precautions has its risks, though in this case they would seem to be small.

Comment: Like this?

`jq -n --arg name "$name" --arg car "$car" --arg colour "$colour" '.profiles += [{$name, $car, $colour}]' > model.json`


So when I add my loop between the jq command and the first set of q&a's, the above works but does not append. Simply overrides the first set of values.

Comment: Even if I pipe the above with `| .profiles += [{$name, $car, $colour}]'`
Returns the same set of values:

```
{
  "profiles": [
    {
      "name": "Paul",
      "car": "Datson",
      "colour": "Brown"
    },
    {
      "name": "Paul",
      "car": "Datson",
      "colour": "Brown"
    }
  ]
}
```

Taking the last entry twice.

Comment: You should drop the `-n` option when reading from model.json

Comment: Thank you peak. 
I have utilised the method you've outlined and unfortunately, the code is still outputting   one set of values (The last set of entries I've input).

No matter how many times I enter values via the loop, only one set is output.  
  
I see the logic in the above code, but not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you have removed the -n option?  Perhaps you should try the very simplest case first, without using sponge.  Add jq `debug` statements to see what's going on.

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure the -n flag has been removed.
So running it in debug mode I see:
`+ jq --arg name Ben --arg car Toyota --arg colour red '.profiles += [{$name, $car, $colour}]' model.json` .......
The subsequent variables are being populated by the last set of entries, which is then outputting only the last set as opposed to appending.

I feel the variables (name, car, & colour) should remain the same because well I'd need the same keys being reflected when iterating through new values.
Maybe it's a version issue? jq version 1.5?

Comment: Are you updating model.json at each iteration, e.g. using `sponge` as shown?

Comment: Yes, exactly how you suggested above. Had to install sponge, but yes.
So the code is; 1. Q&A, 2. Loop of same Q&A for new entries using the same key variables, 3. echo null > model.json, 4. jq command as above piped to sponge model.json, and 5. cat the output

Comment: Finally got it to work! I had to rethink the sequence of events after your last comment.
Basically had to double up on the jq command.
Thank you @peak! Your assistance has been of great help.

Comment: I have another question; how can you utilise the above method as a nested array?
ie.

`{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "profiles": [
    {
      "name": "Joe",
      "car": "BMW",
      "colour": "Red"
    },
    {
      "name": "Peter",
      "car": "Nissan",
      "colour": "White"
    }
  ],
 "key3": "value3",
 "key4": "value4",
 "etc": [
    "blah"
  ],
etc
}`

Had no luck with the following:
`'{$key1, $key2 .profiles += [{$name, $car, $colour}], $key3, $key4, "etc": ["blah"] ' model.json`

Comment: The new question is not too clear, but it looks like you could use the exact same jq program as before.  If that's not the case, and if you cannot figure it out yourself, then I'd suggest asking a new SO question.

Comment: Thank you @peak. Just posted a new related question.

Answer (score 0):

Utilised the method above and still does not append:
ie.

```
Enter name:
Joe
Enter Car Model:
BMW
Enter Colour:
Blue

Add a new entry? (y/n):  y
Enter name:  
Paul
Enter Car Model:  
Nissan
Enter Colour:  
Black

Add a new entry? (y/n):  n



{
  "profiles": [
    {
      "name": "Paul",
      "car": "Nissan",
      "colour": "Black"
    }
  ]
}
```